# JavaFX code editor with content highlighter for Java Code

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I want to write a text editor in JavaFX which acts similar to Eclipse/Netbeans IDE to highlight the Java code.
Can anyone suggest as to how it can be achieved or anyone has done this previously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no pure JavaFX libraries for the code highlighting / editing as far as I know, so if you want to implement it in JavaFX you're going to be translating from a similar Swing (or other) project, or you're on your own.

However, you can use such a Javascript library and wrap it in a WebView if you want to achieve this - Jewelsea (who often swings by here) has done just this and [explained it rather nicely here](http://jewelsea.wordpress.com/2011/12/11/codemirror-based-code-editor-for-javafx/).

Comment: I've published serval blog posts and source code. I've tried both paths:
* embedding a webview and using Orion-Editor written in JS (http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/10/04/eclipse-techs-on-steroids/) 
* writing a native one (http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2013/03/11/build-an-intelligent-code-editor-with-javafx-and-jdt/)

Comment: @tomsontom Nice work! Will it be a free / open product when completed?

Comment: the sources are all free (EPL) and can be found in my github repo at https://github.com/tomsontom/e-fx-clipse and https://github.com/tomsontom/fx-ide

Comment: I integrated the `WebView` based solution berry links with the eclipse compiler for java to create a mini ide which I named [conception](https://github.com/jewelsea/conception).

Answer (score 9):

[RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) let's you specify style classes for ranges of text. Take a look at the [Java keywords demo](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX#automatic-highlighting-of-java-keywords) and [its source code](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/blob/master/richtextfx-demos/src/main/java/org/fxmisc/richtext/demo/JavaKeywords.java).

Comment: Please dont get this, its so frustrating to work with... Im trying to find alternative solutions. I think at this moment in time the best solution would be to use a webview to show a css/javascript code editor like Ace

Answer (score 2):

For any current searchers with this question, [MonacoFX](https://github.com/miho/MonacoFX) is a very nice, convenient, and EASY to use library that offers feature-rich code editing with at least 50 or 75 languages that it can properly syntax highlight, code fold, and all that good stuff. It is the same code editor that is used in the open-source version of Visual Studio. When I built my app and integrated MonacoFX, it was literally the most effortless portion of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eclipse text framework as [posted](https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2015/02/13/how-to-create-an-editor-with-syntax-highlighting-for-java/amp/)

They also have a [javafx code editor component called compensator](https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2015/02/17/compensator-a-code-editor-and-a-code-dev-environment-written-in-javafx/)

you can use intellij's swing code editor, with javafx swing interoperability

the component is `com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorComponentImpl`

you can check details running with [intellij integrated ui inspector](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/internal-ui-inspector.html)